# Space elements inside div

Tags: css, html

I want to have 3 images on the same line, floated to the right, and with some margin between each. If I use the following code:

```
<div style="float:right">
    <img src="http://relevance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/youtube-logo.jpg" width="40">
    <img src="http://relevance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/youtube-logo.jpg" width="40">
    <img src="http://relevance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/youtube-logo.jpg" width="40">
</div>
```

then my images are on the same line but I don't know how to set the margin between each.

If I place each image in its own div such as:

```
<div style="float:right">
    <div style:"margin-left:10"><img src="http://relevance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/youtube-logo.jpg" width="40"></div>
    <div style:"margin-left:10"><img src="http://relevance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/youtube-logo.jpg" width="40"></div>
    <div style:"margin-left:10"><img src="http://relevance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/youtube-logo.jpg" width="40"></div>
</div>
```

then I can set the margin but my images are no longer displayed on the same line, they all float right and end up in one column.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try following

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="abc" > image.. </div>
  <div class="abc" > image.. </div>
  <div class="abc" > image.. </div>
</div>
```

then in css

```
#container{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:auto;
    display:inline;
}
.abc{
    float:right;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

You can check the working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/QjL2D/

Comment: Thanks, works great. What are the overflow:hidden and width:auto for?

Comment: width auto means it will take width as per the contents inside, and overflow:hidden means the content will not go outside the container http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the column-gap property in your css for your desired div id:

```
.container {

    column-gap: 20px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, margin, padding and border are in addition to the element width, rather than included in that width. Though your example doesn't indicate the width of the container div, the behavior indicates it is probably between 120px and 149px, assuming it has no padding or border.

Assuming the container is 120px, you need to either make your images smaller or remove their margins.

Assuming the image size is fixed, you need to either remove the margins or make the container wider.

a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sGxP7/

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-holder"><img src="http://relevance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/youtube-logo.jpg" width="40"></div>
    <div class="image-holder"><img src="http://relevance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/youtube-logo.jpg" width="40"></div>
    <div class="image-holder"><img src="http://relevance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/youtube-logo.jpg" width="40"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    background: #CCC;
}

.image-holder {
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```